# How to filter out writing certain commands in bash history file?

Tags: bash, command-history

I would like to ignore some commands in bash history, for example `exit`, `history`...

I try `HISTIGNORE="history:history :exit:exit "` and it's not filtering out the commands.

How to make sure that the `$HOME/.bash_history` doesn't contains some specific bash commands?

Comment: If the commands are already in the file, you'll need to remove them with an editor. `bash` does little more than read from and append to the on-disk file. All filtering, blocking, etc is done on the in-memory list only.

Comment: Check if the $HISTCONTROL variable is set so that you can filter out commands that are preceded by a space on the command line. This question may be more appropriate on superuser.com, see if this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/384366/remove-a-certain-line-from-bash-history-file

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact matches for the commands to be ignored:

`$export HISTIGNORE="history:exit"`

Put the above shell variable export in your `.bashrc` file so that the next time you login to bash the earlier `HISTIGNORE` setting continues to be effective.

If you don't want any lines beginning with the `history` command, like `history -a` then put this into your `.bashrc` file:

`$export HISTIGNORE="history*:exit"`

If you don't want any commands to be saved into the history, put:

`$export HISTIGNORE="*"`

Check your `HISTIGNORE` setting:

`$echo "$HISTIGNORE"`

From `man bash`:

Each colon-separated list of patterns is anchored at the beginning of the line and must match the complete line. (no implicit '*' is appended). Each pattern is tested against the line after the checks specified by `HISTCONTROL` are applied.

Comment: `HISTIGNORE` does not need to be exported, because it's used by the shell itself, not a child process of the shell.